# HTML Marquee Hspace % wont take

Tags: html, css, marquee

Whenever I try to enter a % into Hspace for Marquee it acts as if nothing is entered.  It only seems to take a pixle value of which I can not properly use becuase of the variation in screen sizes so I would very much like to have it at 100% screen scoll.

Current code:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 150px; left: 0px">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="25
"><img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/jM4bWFBKpSFeo/giphy.gif" width="94" height="88" alt="Swimming fish" hspace= "99%"></marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: height in % will not be taken, only pixel is allowed for height.

Comment: Wow. When I saw the title I thought this was a post from 1990, yet I see the current timestamp. Good for you for keeping the `marquee ` tag alive!

Comment: Do you really need to use the tag or would a javascript solution also work for you?

Comment: `marquee` has never been a valid HTML element. You should avoid it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: As I currently do not know Java or understand it I would much prefer HTML - marquee.  CSS would even be acceptable.  I have used it before many times and just this once I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @AliceI-i As is, marquee would require a little tweaking (I've changed some attributes around as you've probably noticed).  Check out my css animation alternative.  If you don't absolutely need to present a solution to your boss today, please consider making an effort to learn css animations instead.

Answer (score 3):

hspace is still supported in most major browsers, though it wouldn't surprise me if it had problems working with marquee.  Try using margin instead:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="25
"><img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/jM4bWFBKpSFeo/giphy.gif" width="94" height="88" alt="Swimming fish" style="margin: -12px 150px"></marquee>
</div>
```

Please note that marquee is deprecated.  You should consider doing the same thing through css animations instead.  Please see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mt9ungn5/) to see how you can achieve the same thing through css animations.